# Can I use std::partial_sort to sort a std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, partial-sort

There are two arrays, one for ids and one for scores, I want to store the two arrays to a `std::map`, and use the `std::partial_sort` to find the five highest scores, then print their ids
so, Is there any possible to use the `std::partial_sort` on `std::map`?

Comment: You can sort a vector of iterators *to* the map elements.

Comment: Use `map<int, int, std::greater<int> > m;` You can simply store the values from 2 arrays as follows: `m[score] = id;` After you stored all the `score`s and corresponding `id`s, you can consult the starting 5 values of `map` to get the 5 highest `score`s and their corresponding `id`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `std::map`, sorting applies only to keys. You can do it using vector:

```
//For getting Highest first
bool comp(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b){
    return a.second > b.second; 
}
int main() {
    typedef map<int, int> Map;
    Map m = {{21, 55}, {11, 44}, {33, 11}, {10, 5}, {12, 5}, {7, 8}};
    vector<pair<int, int>> v{m.begin(), m.end()};
    std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin()+NumOfHighestScorers, v.end(), comp);
    //....
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/JtqxFW)

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can't rearrange the items in a `std::map`. It always appears to be sorted in ascending key order.